# Point on an anchor on bootstrap modal opening

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I would like to open a help modal, but depending on which link is clicked I need to focus on specific anchor like we do on a FAQ page.
On a page we will add #myAmazingTitle on href link (e.g `<a href="http://....#myAmazingTitle">FAQ</a>` for focusing the display on specific dom element.

```
<h1>My first title</h1>
<h1 id="myAmazingTitle">My Amazing Title</h1> <== Display will be focused on this title
....
```

I would like to have the same behavior with a bootstrap modal.

Is it possible and how?

This is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/2116/) for this issue.

Comment: Please add more info or add jsfiddle snipt

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I managed it, I post the jsfiddle there if someone has the same issue : http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/2116/

Answer (score 1):

Use [`relatedTarget`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target) and HTML `data-*` attributes to specify target element selector (or anchor) and send this value to a handler of `shown.bs.modal` event. See example of usage below.

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var recipient = $(e.relatedTarget).data('focus');
  $(this).find( recipient ).focus();  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <span class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Registration form</span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="EmailInput">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="EmailInput" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="PassInput">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="PassInput" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-focus="#EmailInput">Type Email</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-focus="#PassInput">Type Password</button>
```